# I'm having problems with the button error

Tags: java, android, xml

```java
package com.zairy.app;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
public class MainActivity extends Activity { 
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
    Button toggle = findViewById(R.id.toggle);
    toggle.setOnClickListener(new View.onClickListener) {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, "Alert", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        }
    });
}
```

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button is currently enabled"
        android:id="@+id/text" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/toggle"
        android:onClick="onClick"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="enabled"
        android:layout_below="@+id/text"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Above me is the code provided, I'm having some errors on line 20-26.
Here are the errors ⬇

```
ERROR: <identifier> expected [MainActivity.java:20]
ERROR: illegal start of type [MainActivity.java:20]
ERROR: ';' expected [MainActivity.java:22]
ERROR: ';' expected [MainActivity.java:22]
ERROR: illegal start of type [MainActivity.java:26]
ERROR: package toggle does not exist [MainActivity.java:20]
ERROR: illegal start of type [MainActivity.java:22]
ERROR: modifier public not allowed here [MainActivity.java:22]
```

I hope someone can help me with this.

I keep changing the code, fiddle it around expecting it to work. The other button onClick I used was working well (which is `public void <the variable for the button id> (View v) {}`) but when I used this other method, it didn't work, instead it gives me errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you have written code is wrong, let me correct it:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button toggle = findViewById(R.id.toggle);



        toggle.setOnClickListener(new View.onClickListener) {

            @Override

            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Alert", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        });

    }
}
```

view intialization need to be placed in oncreate() method not outside
and if you want to write it outside of oncreate() method , then make another method and place your code inside it and call that method in onCreate() like below example:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        
        anotherMethod();
    }
    
    private void anotherMethod() {
        Button toggle = findViewById(R.id.toggle);
        toggle.setOnClickListener(new View.onClickListener) {

            @Override

            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Alert", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        });
    }
}
```